# Segmentation Fault when using fopen()

Tags: c, fopen

I'm not sure why this is happening but I am getting a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" from this very simple code. Any ideas as to why? I have to use a string to tell fopen() what file to open.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char *small = "small.ppm";
    FILE * fp;
    char word[5];
    fp = fopen(small, "r");
    fscanf(fp, "%s", word);
    printf("%s\n", word);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fp` is probably `NULL` (you didn't check that the `fopen` succeeded).
How big is the word you are trying to read?

Comment: The first line is just a short 2 character line that reads "P3", which is all I'm trying to read in this instance. The small.ppm file itself has 10 lines of code mostly containing RGB values for a very small picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code could invoke undefined behavior, replace by:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char *small = "small.ppm";
    FILE * fp = fopen(small, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("fopen()");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    char word[5];
    if (fscanf(fp, "%4s", word) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error parsing\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("%s\n", word);
}
```

Comment: @ChristianLindemann well, you get your problem, your program has no access to your file so it can't open it. try `chmod +r small.ppm` in the console.

Comment: A little bit more explanation on what you changed would greatly increase the value of ths answer.

Comment: @Kami I think its pretty self explanatory on what changed assuming you've spent more than an hour reading "how to write C."

Comment: @Kcvin I'd wager that a good amount of students who have C-programming don't understand it completly after 2 semesters. I just think a good answer has to contain more than just the fixed code.

Comment: @KamiKaze "Error checking/handling" is a fundamental that programming students should learn in any 101 class.

Comment: @Kcvin you said it: "should" they get the info presented but my expierience is that quite a bit of them don't understand much of it (and still pass the test

Answer (score 5):

If the file does not exist `fp` will be NULL and so `fscanf(fp, ...)` will segfault.

It's important to check all file operations for success. The usual pattern goes something like...

```
FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
if( fp == NULL ) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open %s: %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}
```